# Как в kohana вывести полную новость?

Tags: action, kohana, база-данных

Создал дополнительный экшн и вид страницы

```
public function action_read()

{   
    $data = array();
    $hom = ORM::factory('News')->where('name','=','url(вот здесь надо сравнить с той статьей по которой кликнули)')->find_all();
    $data['materials'] = $hom;
    $this->template->content = View::factory('ubuntu_read',$data);
}
```

сравниваю по `name`, ссылка будет не по id светиться а по имени, вот так

> site.com/ubuntu/название_статьи

в bootstrap прописал роутер

```
Route::set('ubuntu', 'ubuntu/<action>/<id>')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'ubuntu',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Как можно вывести полную статью?
Надо как то сравнить имя из адресной строки с базой данный, точнее с полем нейм

Answer (score 1):

тут 2 варианта:
 - либо в БД указывайте уникальное имя для каждой статьи (как раз то, что у Вас в адресной строке,
 - либо добавьте id, чтобы он "светился" в адресной строке. Но тогда придётся немного переписать роут.

Кстати, можно ещё вот так модель загружать:

```
$hom = ORM::factory('News', array('name' => article_name);
```